# AIR native c++ extension for android and IOS

Tags: android, ios, air, adobe, native

I want to write a Flex application that uses native c++ code. The application has to be able to run both on Android and IOS.
According to adobe I have to compile the c++ to a shared library (.so) if I want it to run on Android, and to a static library (.a) for IOS.

Is it possible to compile the same c++ code to a shared and static library? Or is there a better way to use the same native c++ code on both Android and IOS?

Comment: cfr. http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/building-ane-ios-android-pt1.html